# The History of Unicode

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, crosswords, word-search

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7352/79067).</sub>

---

[image: The puzzle.]

Here are the pages in text form; it should be pretty self-explanatory, but feel free to ask any questions if something is unclear.

```
╭─────────────────────────────────────╮⎺⎺⎺⎺╭─────────────────────────────────────╮
│ ╓─────────────────────────────────────╮╭─────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ ║                                     ││                                     │ │
│ ║  ┎┬┒                                ││  Part 3:                            │ │
│ ║   ┷ he solution to this puzzle      ││                                     │ │
│ ║  consists of two words. Each small  ││  ♃ ♆ (_o____)                       │ │
│ ║  "part" will have a unique one-     ││                                     │ │
│ ║  word solution. Those parts, in     ││  Part 4:                            │ │
│ ║  turn, will lead to the final       ││          2   4                      │ │
│ ║  answer. Have fun!                  ││ 1 ┏━┱─┬─┬─┐ ┏━┓                     │ │
│ ║                                     ││   ┗━┹─┴─┼─┤ ┡━┩                     │ │
│ ║  Part 1:                            ││   3 ┌─┬─┼─╆━╅─┼─┐                   │ │
│ ║                                     ││     └─┴─╆━╋━┹─┴─┘                   │ │
│ ║  ↖ ↓ ← ↙ ← → ↖ ← ↙ → ↓ ↗            ││   5 ┏━┱─╄━┩        Final word:      │ │
│ ║                                     ││     ┗━┹─┴─┘         1     5         │ │
│ ║  Part 2:                            ││                    ┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐      │ │
│ ║              │♜     ♛   ♜ ♚      │  ││                    └─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘      │ │
│ ║  1 ♕xh5 gxh5 │♟ ♟     ♝ ♟        │  ││                                     │ │
│ ║  2 ♗h7#      │    ♞       ♟      │  ││ Across:          Down:              │ │
│ ║              │      ♝     ♘ ♟    │  ││ 1. ♦             2. Punctuality is  │ │
│ ║              │                   │  ││ 3. Anagram of       a merit.        │ │
│ ║              │  ♙   ♗            │  ││    urge.         4. Beer is bad for │ │
│ ║              │♙ ♗           ♙ ♙ ♙│  ││ 5.  Ꜽ R           his health.     │ │
│ ║              │♖     ♕       ♖ ♔  │  ││                                     │ │
│ ║ 1                                   ││                                   2 │ │
│ ╚═════════════════════════════════════╛╘═════════════════════════════════════╛ │
╰─────────────────────────────────────╯____╰─────────────────────────────────────╯
```

```
╭─────────────────────────────────────╮⎺⎺⎺⎺╭─────────────────────────────────────╮
│ ╓─────────────────────────────────────╮╭─────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ ║                     ││                     │ │
│ ║                                     ││                                     │ │
│ ║ ┌─────────────────────────────────┐ ││  This word search uses the previous │ │
│ ║ │ R E M E M B E R T H E A L A M O │ ││  parts' answers, as well as the     │ │
│ ║ │ E C H O W O R L D S Y N N U B R │ ││  words below:                       │ │
│ ║ │ J O V I A N E T S C A P E L O I │ ││  ┌─┐                                │ │
│ ║ │ O P E R A E C S T A C Y A I N O │ ││  ├─┤  1. ss (again)               │ │
│ ║ │ I E H P O R T S A T A C L O E N │ ││  ├─┤  2.                           │ │
│ ║ │ C N S E P A T T A C K I N D L E │ ││  ├─┤  3. FɪG                        │ │
│ ║ │ E D W A R D E N O B L I N K Y S │ ││  ├─┤  4. cute                     │ │
│ ║ │ M I L L I O N W U R D S T O M P │ ││  ├─┤  5. ☐ without  or ⼇...      │ │
│ ║ │ I N I T I A L R O T T E N E L I │ ││  ├─┤  6.  ' - ap                  │ │
│ ║ │ C G L O O B N A C I R T C E L E │ ││  ├─┤  7.                        │ │
│ ║ │ H R E L Z E L L A L E L D D I M │ ││  ├─┤  8.                          │ │
│ ║ │ A E A A Z G Q C R E S C E N D O │ ││  └─┘  9. Drsc bydkdsyx.             │ │
│ ║ │ E E F F I G Y A R D F A X Y O R │ ││                                     │ │
│ ║ │ L N C I N D E R I D I O T X E H │ ││  At the intersection of a Part      │ │
│ ║ │ A A A A A R D V O R K T R I S C │ ││  solution and each word above is a  │ │
│ ║ │ V P V A P L A I N E R O A E L R │ ││  letter. Put that letter in the     │ │
│ ║ │ A S S A S S I N A T I O N S Y Y │ ││  corresponding box next to its word │ │
│ ║ └─────────────────────────────────┘ ││  above. That will give you the      │ │
│ ║                                     ││  final solution.                    │ │
│ ║ 3                                   ││                                   4 │ │
│ ╚═════════════════════════════════════╛╘═════════════════════════════════════╛ │
╰─────────────────────────────────────╯____╰─────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Please **do not use** a word-search solver or any other computer tools, except for **identifying special Unicode characters**. And just so y'all know, the animation's frames don't have anything to do with solving the puzzle; the animation really was just for fun!

**Partial answers are encouraged**, but please **include the steps you took to get to the solution.**

Comment: That animation and art took quite a while to make -- all the frames are hand-typed. Hope everyone enjoys this, because I did enjoy making it!

Comment: +1 for the animation. It looks prefect!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Final answer:

> [Joe Becker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Becker_(Unicode)), one of the founders of Unicode.

Part 1

> (*Solved by Stiv in the comments.*) If we split the arrows into pairs, they spell **CHROME** in semaphore.

Part 2

> This is known as the [Blackburne's mate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkmate_pattern#Blackburne%27s_mate), so the answer is **BLACKBURNE**. There are curiously ten columns on the chessboard, which might just be a hint at the number of letters in the solution or there might be some other meaning to it. (OP confirmed that it was just a mistake.)

Part 3

> The characters represent Jupiter and Neptune, which are both [Jovian planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_planet) so the answer is **JOVIAN**

Part 4

> The final word is **SPACE**.
>  1A **SUIT**
>  3A **SIMPLE**, an anagram of impels
>  5A **CAR**, based on what the characters look like
>  2D **TIMER**, an anagram of merit and something which should preferably be punctual.
>  4D **AIL**, a homophone of ale
>  [image]

Word Search

> Besides the previous answers we are looking for
>  1. **REJOICE** (joy + ss, again)
>  2. **CRESCENDO**
>  3. **EFFIGY** (rebus)
>  4. **BUNNY**
>  5. **EGG**, a solution to the classic riddle *A box without hinges, key or lid, yet golden treasure inside is hid.* (The last character is a Chinese radical often interpreted as [lid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_8).)
>  6. **CATASTROPHE**, Cat + Apostrophe - ap (as a homophone at least, otherwise it would be cat**o**strophe)
>  7. **KINDLE**
>  8. **ELECTRIC**
>  9. **ROTTEN**, it says *this rotation* with rot-10 applied.
>
>  This gives the following word search
>  [image]

Comment: Good job! You got the final solution right! However, your answers for sections 1 and 4 are incorrect/incomplete. I'll accept it when you finish those last couple parts, but here's an upvote! Of course, here are some hints: rot13 Lbhe nafjre sbe Cneg 1 vf cnegyl pbeerpg, ohg gur neebjf qb zrna fbzrguvat zber fcrpvsvp. Cneg 2: Gur gra pbyhzaf jrer whfg n zvfgnxr :D, but otherwise correct there. Cneg 4: 1N: Lbh zvtug nqq n ♣ . 3N: Nantenz bs nabgure jbeq sbe hetr. 5N: Jung bgure yrggref qbrf gur bprna jnir ybbx yvxr? 2Q: Pbeerpg. 4Q: Ersreraprf n ubzbcubar cnve.

Comment: Re 1: rot13(Gur neebjf jura fcyvg vagb cnvef ner PUEBZR va frzncuber)

Comment: @user39583 rot13 Creuncf V fubhyq unir fnvq n flabalz sbe "hetrf", naq lbhe svefg jbeq (pbzcry) vf irel pybfr, ohg abg dhvgr gur fnzr, nf gur jbeq V'z guvaxvat bs. Nyfb, lbhe frpbaq nafjre sbe 4Q (nvy) vf pbeerpg. Bgure guna gung, 1N, 5N, naq gur nafjre sbe Cneg 4 ner nyy pbeerpg. Good work, you're _very_ close!